# Javascript Clone Document object

Tags: javascript

I have the html page. In that HTML page, Iust want to clone all elements like head,body and other elements .
I can able to get like this

```
const getHeadEle = () => {
    const newHead = document.head.cloneNode(true);
    return newHead.innerHTML;
}
const getBody = () => {
    const head = document.head.cloneNode(true);
    const dom = document.createElement('div');
    dom.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML;
    return dom.innerHTML;
}

const html = `<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head>${getHeadEle()}</head><body>${getBody()}</body></html>`;
```

For now, I get the head element and body element into separate method. Is possible to clone all documents in a line of code?

Comment: If you need the document as string you can just call `document.documentElement.outerHTML;` or with cloneNode like `document.documentElement.cloneNode(true);`

Answer (score 1):

try it ...

```
const getdocument = () => {
   const newDocument = document.cloneNode(true);
   return newDocument ;
}

    const html = getdocument() ;
```